# what functionality does setting the PARENT_ACTIVITY in the manifest file provide?

Tags: android

what functionality does setting the PARENT_ACTIVITY in the manifest file provide?
I played around with it, and from my experience, it doesn't seem to effect the back button functionality (but I could have done something wrong).
Does anyone one know what functionality(ies) this attribute effects?

UPDATE @shoerat: 
TFM is very vague and as I said it didn't seem to affect the back button for me. I removed the parent property from one of my activities and ran my app, and the back button still worked just as before. So this leaves me curious beyond the point of what the manual provides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) says:

The `android:parentActivityName` attribute declares the name of this activity's parent activity within the app's logical hierarchy. The system uses this value to implement default navigation behaviors, such as [Up navigation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) on Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher.

Now, to make it more clear lets take an example ( from the android documentation):

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

In the above example, MainActivity is declared as parent of `SecondActivity` using a metadata element. Now, in the `SecondActivity`'s class, [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) can be used to navigate up to MainActivity(parent activity) when the user presses the up button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

( sniplet taken from [tutorial](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1874864))

The `up` button uses the same resource identifier as the ActionBar home icon, `android.R.id.home`. This [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) might also be relevant to study. It beautifully explains( along with diagrams) the difference in behavior of `Up` button on the device from the `Back` button's behavior.

Under "[Use the New Compatibility Package Classes](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1874864)" heading in the tutorial, the examples explain the use of it very well. Hope all this will help clear the concept a little bit.

Comment: Bingo! I did not know what the "up" button was referring to, I assumed it was another name for the back button. That's why I was confused by the manual. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

It is not *only* for Back button.

[RTFM](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent):

The system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be started when the use presses the Up button in the action bar. The system can also use this information to synthesize a back stack of activities with [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is set for accessing in [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) which has  method `getParentActivityName` on any activity and provides helper functionality for applications implementing recommended Android UI navigation patterns